# Table in the window page should not to have horizontal scroll bar when window size is reduced

Tags: html, css

I've tried

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" 
 cellpadding="0" height="25" width="100%" style='table-layout:fixed' >
```

and

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" 
 cellpadding="0" height="25" width="100%" overflow:hidden >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify two attributes, table-layout:fixed on table and white-space:nowrap; on the cells. You also need to move the overflow:hidden; to the cells too.

```
table {width:100%; table-layout:fixed;}
td {overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
```

You can use `overflow-x:hidden` to hide the text horizontally only when it overflows. Similarly `overflow-y:hidden` to hide vertical scrollbar. Just remember to also set the `table-layout` to `fixed` and the `white-space` to `no-wrap`

Comment: The code I have is a JSP page and when ever I try  "table-layout" and "overflow-x" , it shows undefined attribute name.

Comment: Can you post the full relevant code? Might be a problem somewhere else.